# Prove a graph with n vertices and with a diameter of 15 has a vertex with degree less than n/6

Tags: graph-theory

I need to prove that a graph with n vertices with a diameter of 15 has a vertex with degree less than n/6.

I tried to go with proof by contradiction and see if there's something wrong with the sum of degrees or something like this but found nothing.

Help would be much appreciated

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Can you give some more details about your failed attempts, please?  Did you start with a path of length $15$ and try to prove there is a shorter path between the end vertices, or did you try some other line of attack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $G$ be a graph $n$ vertices and with diameter $15$ in which every vertex has degree at least $\delta$.

Take a vertex $v$ such that there is another vertex at distance $15$ from it.

Notice the graph gets split into $16$ sets $D_0,D_1,\dots, D_{15}$ where $D_i$ is the set of vertices at distance $i$ from $v$.

For each $i$ we have the following: The sum  $|D_{i-1}| + |D_{i}| + |D_{i+1}| > \delta$. This is because otherwise the vertices in $D_i$ would have degree less than $\delta$ (when $i=0,15$ you only get two summands but it's the same thing).

When we add all of these inequalities for the six values of  $i: 0,15,3,6,9,12$ we get $n = \sum\limits_{i} |D_{i-1}| + |D{i}| + |D_{i+1}| > 6\delta$. It follows $\delta < \frac{n}{6}$ as desired.

Comment: Beautiful answer, thank you very much!

Comment: My pleasure ! I was actually kind of shocked how clean it all ended up being !

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the degree of each vertex is at least $\frac n6$
Since the diameter of the graph is $15$ there is a path of length $15$ which is the shortest path between the endpoints.  Let the vertices on this path be $v_1$ through $v_{16}$, in order.  Let $V_k$ be the set of vertices not on the path that are adjacent to $v_k$, $1\leq k\leq16$.

$v_1$ cannot be adjacent to any vertex on the path, other than $v_2$, or there would be a shorter  path, so $|V_1|\geq \frac n6-1.$  We also have $|V_4|\geq \frac n6-2$.  Now note that $V_1\cap V_4=\emptyset$, for if $v\in V_1\cap V_4$, we can replace the path $v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4$ by the shorter path $$v_1, v, v_4$.

Continue in this way, and show that the sum of the number of vertices on the path and off the path is greater than $n$.